# How do I structure 3D Input properly for Keras LSTM

Tags: pandas, numpy, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I have a dataset which contains many snapshot observations in time and a 1 or 0 as a label for each observation.  Lets say each observation contains 3 features.  I am wanting to train an LSTM which will take a sequence of n observations and attempt to classify nth observation as a 1 or 0.

So if we have a dataset that looks like this:

```
# X = [[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0]]
# y = [1, 0, 1, 0]
# so X[0] = y[0], X[1] = y[1]
# . and I would like to input X[0] + X[1] to classify X[1] as y[1]
# . How would I need to structure this below?


X = [[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0]]
y = [1, 0, 1, 0]

def create_model():
  model = Sequential()
  # input_shape[0] is equal to 2 timesteps?
  # input_shape[1] is equal to the 3 features per row?
  model.add(LSTM(20, input_shape=(2, 3)))
  model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
  model.summary()

m = create_model()
m.fit(X, y)
```

So I want `X[0]` and `X[1]` to be the input for one iteration of training and should be classified as `y[1]`.

My question is this.  How do I structure the model in order to take this input properly?  I am very confused by `input_shape`, `features`, `input_length`, `batches` etc ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code snippet might help clarify:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
import numpy as np

# Number of samples = 4, sequence length = 3, features = 2

X = np.array( [ [ [0, 1], [1, 0,], [1, 1] ], 
                [ [1, 1], [1, 1,], [1, 0] ], 
                [ [0, 1], [1, 0,], [0, 0] ], 
                [ [1, 1], [1, 1,], [1, 1] ]] )

y = np.array([[1], [0], [1], [0]])
print(X)
print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(20, input_shape=(3, 2)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

model.fit(X, y)
```

Also, on the Keras documentation page: https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/  look at the example for "Stacked LSTM for sequence classification" near the bottom.  It might help.

In general using Keras, the batch dimension/sample dimension is not specified in layers - it is automatically inferred from the input data.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have the input shape correct.
I would reshape the input data to be (batch_size, timesteps, features)

```
m = create_model()
X.reshape((batch_size, 2, 3))
m.fit(X, y)
```

Common batch sizes are 4, 8 , 16, 32 but for small dataset the impact of the batch size is less important.
And when you want to predict use batch_size = 1